# gcloud docker 409 image conflict error with Node.js

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, express, gcloud

I've got an Express Node app that I'm using with gcloud. When I am running locally using:

```
gcloud preview app run .
```

I am getting this:

```
WARNING: Image Id 2d30351c6647 cannot be removed: 409 Client Error:     
Conflict ("Conflict, cannot delete 404cc995b0da because the running 
container 837a44cae1ee is using it, stop it and use -f to force").
```

The app is running pretty slowly most of the time. When I save, it goes through a slow health check which looks like this:

```
INFO: [default] Detected file changes:
/path/to/server.js
INFO: Building image <appID>.default.1...
INFO: Waiting for instances to restart
INFO: Health checks starting for instance 0.
INFO: default: "GET /_ah/health?IsLastSuccessful=no HTTP/1.1" 503 -
WARNING: All instances may not have restarted
INFO: default: "GET /_ah/health?IsLastSuccessful=no HTTP/1.1" 503 -
```

And then I get the 409 image warning. It slows down considerably, and occasionally crashes all together. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you attach the output of 'docker ps -a'?

Answer (score 2):

Try killing and removing all your running containers on Docker and running it again, that did it for me.

```
docker ps -a
```

(to display all containers, running or not)

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

(to delete all existing containers)